# Is there a command to specify which type of Villager to spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title says, is there a command/tag/anything else that can specify a kind of villager to be spawned using `/summon`? I'm trying to spawn a whole bunch of farmers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I summon villagers with certain professions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343459/how-can-i-summon-villagers-with-certain-professions)

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because the answers here are outdated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Villagers use the `Profession` and `Career` tags to determine their type, as detailed on [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Professions_and_Careers). `Profession` ranges from 0 (Farmer) to 4 (Butcher) and determines the skin of the villager. Trades and actual job are determined by `Career`, the range and meaning depend on the `profession`.

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0, Career:1}
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:2, Career:1}
```

Can be used to create a Farmer and a Cleric villager, respectively.

(Note: I didn't test it myself (not at comp), so there might be errors in the command structure.)

Comment: thx! I need help with this too. Thing is, I don't know which numbers are equivalent to a specific profession/carrier. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @DragonHatchling there's a table on the [wiki page I linked](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Villager#Professions_and_careers) which has all the Career and Profession numbers.

Answer (score 3):

```
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,Career:0}
```

The "~ ~ ~" are the coordinates (location) where the mob will spawn, the first and third are lateral directions, and the second means the height. In my command there, it means the villager will spawn 1 block above wherever you run the command.

The profession is the type of villager you want.

- 0 = Farmer, Fisherman, Shepherd, Fletcher
- 1 = Librarian
- 2 = Cleric
- 3 = Armorer, Weapon Smith, Tool Smith
- 4 = Butcher, Leatherworker

You can even change their name.

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:0}
```

Where the "0" is is where you can put in your own name to give them.

Answer (score 0):

For 1.13 the command is as follows
`/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~1 ~ {Profession:0,Career:0}`

Answer (score -1):

To get farmers, do `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:1}`.

To get fishermen, do `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:2}`.

To get shepherds, do `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:3}`.

To get fletchers, do `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:4}`.

To get nitwits, do `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:5,Career:1}`.

Profession is the villager type. Career is the villager job.

> {Profession:0,Career:1-4} = Farmer (Brown Dude)
>
> {Profession:1,Career:1-2} = Librarian (White Dude)
>
> {Profession:2,Career:1} = Priest (Pink Dude)
>
> {Profession:3,Career:1-3} = Blacksmith (Black Apron Dude)
>
> {Profession:4,Career:1-2} = Butcher (White Apron Dude)
>
> {Profession:5,Career:1} = Nitwit (Green Dude)
>
> *See the two numbers with hyphens in between them after Career? That means you get to pick a number between those two numbers.

Answer (score -1):

{Profession:0,Career:1-4} = Farmer (Brown Dude)

{Profession:1,Career:1-2} = Librarian (White Dude)

{Profession:2,Career:1} = Priest (Pink Dude)

{Profession:3,Career:1-3} = Blacksmith (Black Apron Dude)

{Profession:4,Career:1-2} = Butcher (White Apron Dude)

{Profession:5,Career:1} = Nitwit (Green Dude)

NOT COPIED FROM SOME1 ELSE