# Is it possible to make a villager you cannot interact?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make something like the morph mod, where you can become a mob, but with a villager, when I want to right click, I interact with the villager.

How to make it so that I cannot interact with a villager, even without a profession just with commands?

Edit: Sorry, I meant to stop villager interaction completely. That means no trading, no nodding villagers. And so I can open doors like it's not actually there.

Answer (score 1):

There is. It is a villager that has a profession of "nitwit" it doesn't have any jobs, and it does nothing, also it is spawnable on survival.

to spawn a nitwit villager with commands, just do:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:5,Career:1}
```

> (from
> [Is there a command to specify which type of Villager to spawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193098/is-there-a-command-to-specify-which-type-of-villager-to-spawn))

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to completely stop interaction with villagers, which means no trading, no nodding villagers. I want to make the right clicking completely stop, and so I can open a door like it's not there.

Comment: you can do /summon villager ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}